# C# Emgucv2.4 or 3.1 disable the stitching wave correction

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I have been trying to stitch images using the sample program, but it continually runs out of memory .

There appears to be a successful fix for this by turning off the "wave correction". While this can apparently be easily done in openCV, I cannot figure out how to do it in EMGU C#.

below is my snippet C#.

```
// Collect all images
            List<Image<Bgr, Byte>> sourceImages = new List<Image<Bgr, Byte>>(); 

            for (int i = 1; i <7 ; i++)
            {
                string fileN = fl1 + "n (" + i.ToString() + ").jpg";
                sourceImages.Add(new Image<Bgr, Byte>(fileN));
            }

            try
            {
                using (Stitcher stitcher = new Stitcher(false))
                {
                    // Stitch images
                    Image<Bgr, Byte> result = stitcher.Stitch(sourceImages.ToArray());
                    Bitmap bm = result.ToBitmap();
                    bm.Save(fl1 + "resul.jpeg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                }
            }
            finally
            {

            }
```

Answer any version  2.4 or 3.1 is welcome

Answer (score 0):

Try using below before you try to stitch:

```
stitcher.WaveCorrection = false;
```

extra info [here](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.3.0/document/html/6e8e33bd-20e2-70a0-98f0-af864c060533.htm)